# Why can C++ ternary operator return type not be a base class type?

Tags: c++

If I get it correctly, the ternary operator has a return type. The return type is deduced from the second and third argument types of the ternary operator. If I write a ternary operator without using its result (L2 below), there is no other information to deduce the return type. So, if we want to have a single way to deduce the return type, we cannot rely on, for instance, the type of the variable in which we put the value returned by the ternary operator (L1 below).

But, instead of trying to convert types to each other, which may not be possible, why not introduce the base class use case in the standard?

That is, if there is a common base class to arguments 2 and 3, use it as the return type for the ternary operator (in a compatible way to other existing rules) for reference/pointer types. It would allow a one-line const reference/pointer initialization (like L3 below, but with no cast).

I guess there is a good reason to not do so.

```
class A {};
class B : public A {};
class C : public A {};

int main()
{
  B* b = new B;
  C* c = new C;
  A * a1 = true ? b : c; // L1 does not compile
  true ? b : c; // L2 does not compile
  const A * a2 = false ? static_cast<A*>(b) : static_cast<A*>(c); // L3 does compile
}
```

EDIT: Corrected example to reflect that the question is not related to slicing.

EDIT: To be clear, I am not asking why the code does not compile. Tons of questions exist asking why. I am asking why the C++ standard does not implement a rule to make L1 compile.

Comment: In particular, this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/49240345/817643 demonstrates difficulties

Comment: It's called the conditional operator, and the expression is a conditional expression.

Comment: As in your example we have object slicing which is typically not very useful. If a user *really* wants to do it, it is quite ok to put the cast inside. Another case where we have silently object slicing is not what I would see in the standards. And in case of multiple inheritance, diamonds and much more complex inheritance, what should the result type be? The only use case I see is giving back a base pointer for polymorphic types, but this is already there.

Comment: @Klaus I edited the example to reflect the question. No slicing involved. Your point about inheritance is a good one. In this case, a cast would be mandatory to disambiguate. What do you mean by « it is already there » ?

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica the question you reference answers why my code does not compile but this is not my question. It is not at all a duplicate.

Comment: Did you go and read the answer I explicitly linked? And it is the same question. Like literally.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica Well, let's not start a flame war. I obviously did. I edited my question to clarify this point. I am not asking why it dose not compile. I am asking why the standard could not be modified in order to make it compile. If the linked answer does answer that, I failed to understand the explanation. I only saw a quotation that explains why it does not compile.

Comment: I linked to a specific answer by bolov under that other Q. The very first comment under this post.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica OK, I understand now. This answer *is about* my question, even if it answers a different question than mine. But the comment to the question saying that cases of ambiguity do not prevent handling cases of no ambiguity, is, to me, correct. And that leads to… my question.

Comment: No, that just leads to this really being a duplicate. The other question asks what'd be the problem. The OP there may have been satisfied with a standard quote, but it doesn't make this an entirely different question. The mechanism SO gives us when we want a new answer to an existing question is to post a bounty. We do not repost the question and claim it's different under a fig leaf of wanting more of an explanation.